# Which forms of JavaScript for intermediate-level Rails developer, only dev on team?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I am acting as web developer for a small startup, taking over as the only in-house developer to maintain and adapt the application that was initially put together by a team of contractors. I would consider myself to be at an intermediate level with Ruby on Rails. I know enough about front end technologies like HTML and CSS to use Bootstrap or Foundation effectively and write my own tweaks when necessary. However, I only can read the JavaScript code of other developers well enough to make small modifications to what's already in place.

I would like to become proficient in JavaScript to help round out my skillset but there seem to be a lot of JavaScript "options" out there and I'm not sure what's on the way in, what's on the way out, what's popular, what's most useful, easiest to start with, best fit for Rails applications and so forth. And by "options" I mean "regular" Javascript, jQuery, Node, Angular, etc etc.

In hopes that my question will meet SO terms as "answerable" I'd like to focus on the question of what kind of Javascript fits best with Rails and which technologies are the most generally relevant today (i.e. not on the way out of popularity already).

Comment: [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Your choice should depend on what you're doing. One case might be using Rails primarily on the back-end, pulling data from it, and then generating your markup and displaying content primarily on the front-end with JavaScript. In that case, you should look into a JavaScript framework like [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) or [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). If you're going to be generating your markup primarily on the back-end with Rails, having that markup being pre-populated with content before being sent to the user, you might be better off using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for DOM manipulation and the occasional AJAX request to your Rails back-end.

In the case you're looking for a framework: [Yehuda Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/) is a leading voice in the Ruby on Rails core team, and has a similar role inside of the [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) project. While this isn't strictly objective, I'd say that Ember is the JavaScript framework that most closely matches "The Rails Way". That said, any framework will integrate well if you're using Rails as a backend, and [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) is currently more popular and might be easier if you're looking for examples and helper libraries.

I'd like to point out that Ember is just a framework, just like jQuery is just a library. Knowing JavaScript from the bottom up is a very helpful thing when working with anyone's code. I highly recommend checking out the [Learn JavaScript page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/learn/javascript), and maybe picking up a copy of [JavaScript: the Good Parts by Douglas Crockford](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do). The former has a bunch of free information about getting up to speed on JavaScript. The latter is a dense, and somewhat controversial book, but (in my opinion) is one of the best books about dealing with the language's rough edges.

Comment: I'd say be careful with Crockford's book - it's an odd mix of basic JS syntax and ideas with more difficult OOP and functional design concepts. But to each his own :)